# Set buttons ids with Custom Adapter

Tags: android, android-layout

Which will be the better way to create a Vertical Lineal layout with four or more buttons in each row

The problems I have face are the following:

- Setting the id of each button manually will result in a lot of repetitive code, more resources usage and you will have to change everyone to add a feature or change something (I think using an adapter will be the most efficient way, but...)
- From what I know using a CustomAdapter don't help you set a unique ID to the buttons

Can you use an adapter to set a different id for each button dipending of the row?

Example:

```
second button of third row: r3b2
fifth button of first row: r1b5
```

Thanks.

Comment: you can always use `View.get/setTag()`

Answer (score 0):

You can create the buttons programmatically in our Activity class like this

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layout); // the layout in which u want to display the buttons
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    int count = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { // i = row count
        LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        row.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) { // j = column count (create 7 buttons in each row)
                int id = count;
                final Button btnTag = new Button(getActivity());
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                params.weight = 1;
                params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
                btnTag.setLayoutParams(params);
                btnTag.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
                String dateSuffix = count + getDayNumberSuffix(count);
                btnTag.setTag(dateSuffix);
                btnTag.setId(id);
                btnTag.setText(count + "");
                btnTag.setTextSize(12.0f);
                    btnTag.setOnClickListener(getOnClickDoSomething(btnTag, count));
                row.addView(btnTag);
                count++;
        }
        layout.addView(row);
    }

View.OnClickListener getOnClickDoSomething(final Button btnTag, final int count) {
    return new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // here you can do what u want to do on button click
        }
}
```